# For Loop Across Specific Column Range in R

Tags: r

I have a wide data frame consisting of 1000 rows and over 300 columns.  The first 2 columns are GroupID and Categorical fields.  The remaining columns are all continuous numeric measurements.  What I would like to do is loop through a specific range of these columns in R, beginning with the first numeric column (column #3).  For example, loop through columns 3:10.  I would also like to retain the column names in the loop.  I've started with the following code using

```
for(i in 3:ncol(df)){
  print(i)
}
```

But this includes all columns to the right of column #3 (not the range 3:10), and this does not identify column names.  Can anyone help get me started on this loop so I can specify the column range and also retain column names? TIA!

Side Note:  I've used tidyr to gather the data frame in long format.  That works, but I've found it makes my data frame very large and therefore eats a lot of time and memory in my loop.

Comment: You can subset your data with`df[,3:10]` no need of loop unless you need to compute something; in such case loops are also not needed. What do you need to do over your col range?

Comment: Thanks but I think a loop of some sort is still needed.  I need to use ggplot2 to produce a graph of each column with one of the two group variables. So I will need to produce x number of graphs for x number of columns specified.

Comment: I have added a similar sketch for plot, using dummy data with same dim like yours. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not include your data, I created a similar dummy data (`1000` rows and `302` columns, `2` id vars ) in order to show you how to select columns, and prepare for plot:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
#Dummy data
Numvars <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000*300),nrow = 1000,ncol = 300))
vec1 <- 1:1000
vec2 <- rep(paste0('class',1:5),200)
IDs <- data.frame(vec1,vec2,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Bind data
Data <- cbind(IDs,Numvars)
#Select vars (in your case 10 initial vars)
df <- Data[,1:12]
#Prepare for plot
df.melted <- melt(data = df,id.vars = c('vec1','vec2'))
#Plot
ggplot(df.melted,aes(x=vec1,y=value,group=variable,color=variable))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~vec2)
```

You will end up with a plot like this:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep column names by feeding them into an `lapply` function, here's an example with the iris dataset:

```
  lapply(names(iris)[2:4], function(columntoplot){

   df <- data.frame(datatoplot=iris[[columntoplot]])
  
   graphname <- columntoplot
  
    ggplot(df, aes(x = datatoplot)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    ggtitle(graphname)
  
  ggsave(filename = paste0(graphname, ".png"), width = 4, height = 4)
  
})
```

In the `lapply` function, you create a new dataset comprising one column (note the double brackets). You can then plot and optionally save the output within the function (see `ggsave` line). You're then able to use the column name as the plot title as well as the file name.